# What to write in "try" statement - Java - Exception Handling?

Tags: java, try-catch

Got another question in Java - this time about exception handling - and I can't seem to find a specific answer.

I have a Main Class and a Customer Class as well as the Exception class (but I didn't paste that here):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
try
{
    // what can i write in here to make this a valid exception?
    System.out.println("test");
}

catch (InvalidCustomer e)
{
    System.err.println("test");
}
```

I am getting an error in the "catch" statement - "exception is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement".

**The problem I am having is - I don't know what to write in the try statement to make this work.**

```
public String Customer(String model) throws InvalidCar
{
    String carModel;

    if (validateCar(carModel))
    {
        carModel = model;
    }
    else
    {
        InvalidCar f = new InvalidCar(carModel);
        throw f;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated - I am super confused about it and maybe I am just asking the wrong question?

Comment: You need to add some code that is susceptible of throwing an InvalidCustomer exception. Note that exception classes should enad with the word "Exception", by convention. See the catch block as a seat belt: you fasten your seat belt when on a plane or in a car, because there is a "chance" of an accident to happen. But not when sitting at a table, because an accident will never happen there.

Comment: Normally, you write something that throws an `Exception` within a `try`-block. The `catch`-block(s) is (are) then able to catch the `Exception`(s) thrown within the `try` block to react accordingly. For more information, check out the [Oracle track about Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Comment: if you just want to check how exception handling works you can explicitly throw the exception from the try block:
something like : throw new InvalidCustomer();

Comment: What is a `InvalidCustomer` and how is it created? Is `InvalidCar` an `InvalidCustomer` exception, and if so what causes a car to not validate?

Comment: (Who else then me could give a hint on this...) The compiler warning or error you get tells you that you try to catch an exception thats not thrown. Since it's your custom Exception class your `println()` statement can't throw it. You may want to add a `throw new InvalidCustomer()` statement taht might get thrown contidionally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your function - the `Customer(string model)` in your try block. Then the exception can be thrown and you won't get the error anymore, like this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        // what can i write in here to make this a valid exception?
        String model = Customer("myModel");
    }
    catch (InvalidCar e)
    {
        System.err.println("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: This works if `Customer()` throws `InvalidCar`. You'd have to change the signature of `Customer()` to do this: `public String Customer(String model) throws InvalidCar {...`

Comment: Thanks for helping me out on this.is It's giving me a new error on the "string model" line now - "cannot find symbol".

Comment: Hello Justin - you have to change `string` to `String` - I have also updated my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

That because your try block never throw `InvalidCustomer` and if you use your `Customer` function above, that may only throw `InvalidCar` which is in this case is not sub-class of `InvalidCustomer`.

This may work as you expected:

```
public String Customer(String model) throws InvalidCustomer{
String carModel;

if (validateCar(carModel))
{
    carModel = model;
}
else
{
    throw new InvalidCustomer();
}
```

and then, in your `main()` :

```
    try{
    String model = Customer("Illegal Model");
    }catch(InvalidCustomer e){
    System.out.println("gotcha");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out on this.is It's giving me a new error on the "string model" line now - "cannot find symbol".

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is because there is no code within the try block that will throw the exception.

`System.out.println("test");` does not throw an exception.

To make it work, call the method that throws the InvalidCustomer exception.

Write `String customer = Customer("carModel");` within the try block. Also make sure that this method actually does throw InvalidCustomer. Looks like it just throws InvalidCar exception.
And it would be better to rename your method (Customer) to lower case 'c'.